# SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar with linked OLAP server doesn't return any value

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, olap

I have problem  with executing query using `SqlCommand`, I'm using `ExecuteScalar()` method and passing open query to it:

```
 SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(MY_OLAP,
'WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Out] AS
''[Measures].[Hours]''
 SELECT NON EMPTY [Machine].[Stops].[All]
 ON ROWS, [Measures].[Out] ON COLUMNS FROM [Machines]')
```

and trying to execute query against linked OLAP server but only thing 
I get is `object=null` or empty result, but  when I run same query in management studio it's returning correct values.

```
 SqlConnection cubeConnection = new SqlConnection(cubeConnectonString);
            using (SqlCommand cubeCmd = new SqlCommand(cubeQuery, cubeConnection))
            {
                cubeConnection.Open();
                var tmp = cubeCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (tmp==null) {
                    cuberesult = "0";
                }
                else tmp.ToString();

            }
```

I added linked OLAP server than I add linked server login with my domain user in order to have access to this cube, I login to server using standard authentication,  but this doesn't help. Some one have idea what I'm missing.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server='MY_OLAP',
    @srvproduct='', 
    @provider='MSOLAP', 
    @datasrc='MYSQLSERVER', 
    @catalog='CUBE'
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I have recently read that this is only possible if you have a 32bit SQL Server. Do you have X64? I'll try to find that in writing if I can.

Comment: additionally, you might have double-hop issues. Is SSAS on the same server as MS SQL RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the last chapter of [this article](http://sqlmag.com/reporting/access-analysis-services-cubes-wcf) can help you. They play with authorization a lot. For example:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'SSAS',@useself=N'False',
    @locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

Also there is a veeery little possibility, that you have a mistake with quotes or similar in code, that puts your query in cubeQuery variable. @ is a safe way.

```
 string cubeQuery = @"SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(MY_OLAP,
'WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Out] AS
''[Measures].[Hours]''
 SELECT NON EMPTY [Machine].[Stops].[All]
 ON ROWS, [Measures].[Out] ON COLUMNS FROM [Machines]')";
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.